# drupal 8 Restore client's original IP address from apache behind nginx

Tags: proxies

Is there any simple method can i restore client's original IP address behind nginx?

i've tried to add the following code in settings.php, but not work

```
$settings['reverse_proxy'] = TRUE;
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP'])) {
  $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP'];
}
```

i use contact form to test and see the ip flood table it is still a server ip address. any ideas?